# How to tweak biblatex-chicago to include full page range in first citation even when citing a specific page

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

By default, `biblatex-chicago` (in Author-Title mode) cites `@article`s and `@incollection`s the first time with a full page range UNLESS the cite command includes a specific page citation, in which case only the latter is printed.

How can I tweak the style to make first-time citations print the full page range followed, when applicable, by comma + "at" + the specific page/pages cited? (When the first-time citation has no page citation, the output would be identical.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[162]{hyman}.

\cite[220--222]{doody}.

\cite[163]{hyman}.
\cite[223]{doody}.

\end{document}
```

Default output:

> Arthur Hyman, “Aristotle’s Theory of the Intellect and its
> Interpretation by Averroes,” in *Studies in Aristotle*, ed. Dominic J.
> O’Meara, Studies in Philosophy and the History of Philosophy 9
> (Washington, D.C.: The Catholic University of America Press, 1981),
> 162.
>
> Terrence Doody, “Hemingway’s Style and Jake’s Narration,” *The Journal
> of Narrative Technique* 4, no. 3 (1974): 220–222.
>
> Hyman, “Aristotle’s Theory of the Intellect,” 163. Doody, “Hemingway’s Style and Jake’s Narration,” 223.

Desired output (boldface added to mark the differences):

> Arthur Hyman, “Aristotle’s Theory of the Intellect and its
> Interpretation by Averroes,” in *Studies in Aristotle*, ed. Dominic J.
> O’Meara, Studies in Philosophy and the History of Philosophy 9
> (Washington, D.C.: The Catholic University of America Press, 1981), **161–191, at**
> 162.
>
> Terrence Doody, “Hemingway’s Style and Jake’s Narration,” *The Journal
> of Narrative Technique* 4, no. 3 (1974): **212–225, at** 220–222.
>
> Hyman, “Aristotle’s Theory of the Intellect,” 163. Doody, “Hemingway’s Style and Jake’s Narration,” 223.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `verbose` styles have an option called `citepages` for that. `biblatex-chicago` does not appear to have a similar option.

Something like the following appears to work, but as always, it is tricky to modify a highly customised style like `biblatex-chicago`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  thiscite = {at},
}

\newtoggle{cbxchic:hadpages}

\renewbibmacro*{fullpostnote}{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbxchic:hadpages}%
  \iffieldundef{chapter}%
   {\iffieldundef{pages}%
      {\global\togglefalse{cbxchic:hadpages}}%
      {\postnotedelim%
        \printfield{pages}}}%
   {\postnotedelim%
    \printfield{chapter}}%
  \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
      and
      test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
      and
      togl {cbxchic:hadpages}
    }
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \bibstring{thiscite}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{semel:postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{eid+fullpostnote}{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbxchic:hadpages}%
  \iffieldundef{chapter}%
    {\iffieldundef{pages}%
      {\iffieldundef{eid}%
        {\global\togglefalse{cbxchic:hadpages}}%
        {\postnotedelim%
          \printfield{eid}%
          \clearfield{eid}}}%
      {\postnotedelim%
        \printfield{pages}}}%
    {\postnotedelim%
      \printfield{chapter}}%
  \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
      and
      test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
      and
      togl {cbxchic:hadpages}
    }
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \bibstring{thiscite}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{semel:postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[162]{hyman}.

\cite[220--222]{doody}.

\cite[163]{hyman}.
\cite[223]{doody}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Arthur Hyman, “Aristotle’s Theory of the Intellect and its Interpretation by Averroes,” in Studies in Aristotle, ed. Dominic J. O’Meara, Studies in Philosophy and the History of Philosophy 9 (Washington, D.C.: The Catholic University of America Press, 1981), 161–191, at 162.]

Comment: That seemed to do it. Thank you!

Comment: I've noticed a small issue with this tweak, prompting to ask a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561566/fixing-punctuation-in-biblatex-after-a-close-parenthesis-while-using-custom-macr).